# How to use columns with special characters in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I'm pretty new to the Altair library. I'm having difficulties producing graphs if the variable to be plotted has an object dtype in the pandas dataframe.

I tried a barchart and a boxplot without much luck. Any help is much appreciated.

**Barchart:**
I'm trying to create a chart that looks like the following:

[image: Desired Barchart]

I have read the Altair documentation and tried the following code:

```
alt.Chart(psy).mark_bar().encode(x = alt.X('player.q_mother_language', title = 'Mother language'), y  ='count()', color = 'player.q_mother_language')
```

The graph that the code delivers is:

[image]

**Boxplot**
Then I decided to try some boxplots.

THe boxplot that I want to produce is:

[image]

The code I have used is:

```
alt.Chart(psy).mark_boxplot().encode(x = 'player.q_gender', y = 'player.q_age', color = 'player.q_gender')
```

The result I get is:

[image]

The dataset looks like the following:

```
player.q_mother_language,player.q_country,player.q_age,player.q_gender
Czech,Czech,21,Male
Serbian,Serbia,23,Female
German,Austria,26,Male
German,Austria,21,Female
Portuguese,Portugal,21
Russian,Kazakhstan,22,Female
Mongolian,Mongolia,32,Female
Ukrainian,Ukraine,19,Female
German,Austria,22,Male
```

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that special characters in column names (including periods, brackets, and quotations) are used to indicate hierarchical variables. To proceed with your chart, you should either rename the columns so they don't contain special characters, or escape those special characters in the chart encoding.

Here is an example of the latter approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import altair as alt

data = """player.q_mother_language,player.q_country,player.q_age,player.q_gender
Czech,Czech,21,Male
Serbian,Serbia,23,Female
German,Austria,26,Male
German,Austria,21,Female
Portuguese,Portugal,21
Russian,Kazakhstan,22,Female
Mongolian,Mongolia,32,Female
Ukrainian,Ukraine,19,Female
German,Austria,22,Male
"""

psy = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

alt.Chart(psy).mark_bar().encode(
    x= alt.X(r'player\.q_mother_language', type='nominal', title = 'Mother language'),
    y='count()',
    color=alt.Color(r'player\.q_mother_language', type='nominal')
)
```

[image]